# Symbolic link to application - working directory

Tags: bash, application

Lets say i have a bash script in a folder called `Programming`, which reads data from files in a subfolder named `data`.
The paths in the script to the files are all relative to this "Programming" folder.
`echo "test" > ./data/test.txt`.
So the working directory should always be the "Programming" folder.
When the script passes all tests, it is finished and i thought i could easily copy the whole content of the "Programming" folder to a subfolder in `/opt`, lets say `/opt/myapplication` and then make a symbolic link in the `/usr/bin` folder called `myapplication`, which links to the script in `/opt/myapplication/bash_script` to make it reachable in the environment.

But the problem is, if i now call myapplication from anywhere the working directory is

```
$PWD= #actual shell directory at script start
$0=/usr/bin/myapplication
${BASH_SOURCE[0]}=/usr/bin/myapplication
```

and my application fails. I thought the symbolic link will change the working directory, to where the file is located.

What is the common practice in Unix to set the working directory always, to where the executed file is located, to use relative paths ??

Comment: @lkkachu You are right, the working directory is the actual shell directory, where the script is started. I got /usr/bin because i was in /usr/bin at start time of myapplication, if i call myapplication from root, then PWD="/"   , my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the common practice in Unix to set the working directory always, to where the executed file is located, to use relative paths ??

There isn't, really. In most cases, you could use `$0` and do a `cd` inside the script based on that, but what shows in `$0` might not help that much,
as it could itself be a relative path, or it could be a path through a symlink instead.

<sub>(And for binary executables that get their `argv[0]` directly from the caller, it could be set to anything in the `execve()` call, `(exec -a anything /path/to/file)` in Bash. That doesn't work the same for `$0` in scripts due to how they're started.)</sub>

But, another question is if you should even do that anyway. The common idea is that the tools reside in some directory in `PATH`, and then they're used from the directory where the data files are. That way, a single tool can be used for more than one set of data files, and by different users.

Another common way to set a default path, is to use an environment variable. Have the script contain something like `if [ -d "$MYAPP_DIR" ]; then cd "$MYAPP_DIR"; fi`, and then the user can set `MYAPP_DIR` in their shell's startup files as they wish.

Of course, there might be some static data the tool needs and that comes with the tool. For finding those, I can see some possibilities:

- Use a fixed path to a config file that tells the location of the static data. That fixed path would usually be something like `/etc/mytool/config` or so. The downside here is that it doesn't really work for a non-admin install.
- Set the location at compile time and store it in the binary itself. The path to data would usually be something like `/usr/share/lib/mytool/whatever`, but could be something else, but probably doesn't change during the lifetime of the installation.
  (I think this is rather common, but in a way, it somehow feels ugly, IMO.)
- Use an environment variable. The downside here is that then the user has to set it for anything to work, so maybe it's better to use this as an alternative/override to the others.

Comment: @ikkachu it was my fault in explaining, the data the script needs is config data (standard values) and manual data. After reading your answer, i think its a bad idea to work with relative pathes, and only use absolute pathes, putting the config data in /etc and the manual in /usr/share/man or copy all information in the script file.

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza, edited a bit for static data

Comment: @ikkachu after thinking a lot about this, i came to the conclusion, that i had a massive fault in thinking. When the user is in a folder called test and inside test folder, there is a file1, the advantage of relative pathes would be, that he can e.g. list this file in a short way with ls file1, if the working directory, would be always set, to where the command is executed, it would be /usr/bin and ls would not find any file1 in /usr/bin or list the wrong file. So that would make relative pathes on userside senseless. Then the user has to always use absolute pathes.

Comment: @ikkachu so the working directory must always be, the actual shell directory, when the command is started and thats good so.

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza, in general, yes! Though if the tool does something that doesn't really ever rely on user files, then you can break that "rule". I think I have written system-specific scripts that only ever work with one particular set of data and do `cd /some/particular/path` at the very start. But general-purpose tools and single-purpose one-off tools are different.

Comment: @ikkachu Hi again, i now know, how you can find out, where the script is executed. I got this from the man, who wrote the bash file AppRun for inkscape, which is inside Inkscape image. He uses ```HERE="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "${0}")")"```to find out, where i put the whole AppImage data, thx for your time.

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza, oh right, that's true, you could use `readlink -f` or `realpath` to resolve a relative path or one with a  symlink.